# jquery problem internet explorer 9 and 7

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yanMenu ul").hide();
    $("div#button").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("normal");
        });
    });


                        <div id="yanMenu">          
                           <div id="button"><h5>Kategori 1</h5></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Secenek 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secenek 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secenek 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secenek 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
<!-- This code it doesnt work!-->
                        <div id="yanMenu">          
                               <div id="button"><h5>Kategori 1</h5></div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Secenek 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Secenek 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Secenek 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Secenek 4</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
<!-- This code it doesnt work!-->
```

It is toggle menu script . When i was copy again this html code, It didnt work in ie9 and ie 7 What Can i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using the same ID's more than once in the page.
ID's should be unique (only one instance per page)

Try using classes instead.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".yanMenu ul").hide();
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("normal");
        });
    });


     <div class="yanMenu">          
      <div class="button"><h5>Kategori 1</h5></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
   <div class="yanMenu">          
      <div class="button"><h5>Kategori 1</h5></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Secenek 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID values should be unique (I would assume that your compiler may give you a warning if you have duplicated). These can fall under the same class or you can even use name attribute for your markup.

```
$('div[class="toggle"]').click(function(){.....}
<div id="button1" class="toggle">
<div id="button2" class="toggle">
```

...or name attribute instead of class but class is prob the preferable way to go

Comment: ('div[class="toggle"]') is a whole lot slower than ('.toggle')  check out this performance test I just made. http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-vs-class-selection